# Could not resolve "date-fns/_lib/cloneObject/index.js"

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, date-fns

I have an AWS CDK project initialized with AWS CDK CLI. I want to deploy a AWS Lambda NodeJS function to the cloud, but it throws an error

After running this command in termnial

```
$ npx cdk deploy --hotswap-fallback --context env=dev --profile il-john
```

it shows this error

```
Bundling asset projectApiStack/createWorkingDay/Code/Stage...
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "date-fns/_lib/cloneObject/index.js"

    node_modules/date-fns-tz/esm/formatInTimeZone/index.js:1:24:
      1 │ import cloneObject from 'date-fns/_lib/cloneObject/index.js'
        ╵                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  The path "./_lib/cloneObject/index.js" is not exported by package "date-fns":

    node_modules/date-fns/package.json:19:13:
      19 │   "exports": {
         ╵              ^

  You can mark the path "date-fns/_lib/cloneObject/index.js" as external to exclude it from the
  bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle.

✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "date-fns/_lib/cloneObject/index.js"

    node_modules/date-fns-tz/esm/zonedTimeToUtc/index.js:1:24:
      1 │ import cloneObject from 'date-fns/_lib/cloneObject/index.js'
        ╵                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  The path "./_lib/cloneObject/index.js" is not exported by package "date-fns":

    node_modules/date-fns/package.json:19:13:
      19 │   "exports": {
         ╵              ^

  You can mark the path "date-fns/_lib/cloneObject/index.js" as external to exclude it from the
  bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle.

✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "date-fns/format/index.js"

    node_modules/date-fns-tz/esm/format/index.js:1:26:
      1 │ import dateFnsFormat from 'date-fns/format/index.js'
        ╵                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  The path "./format/index.js" is not exported by package "date-fns":

    node_modules/date-fns/package.json:19:13:
      19 │   "exports": {
         ╵              ^

  You can mark the path "date-fns/format/index.js" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which
  will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle.

✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "date-fns/_lib/toInteger/index.js"

    node_modules/date-fns-tz/esm/toDate/index.js:1:22:
      1 │ import toInteger from 'date-fns/_lib/toInteger/index.js'
        ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  The path "./_lib/toInteger/index.js" is not exported by package "date-fns":

    node_modules/date-fns/package.json:19:13:
      19 │   "exports": {
         ╵              ^

  You can mark the path "date-fns/_lib/toInteger/index.js" as external to exclude it from the
  bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle.

✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "date-fns/_lib/getTimezoneOffsetInMilliseconds/index.js"

    node_modules/date-fns-tz/esm/toDate/index.js:2:44:
      2 │ import getTimezoneOffsetInMilliseconds from 'date-fns/_lib/getTimezoneOffsetInMilliseconds/index.js'
        ╵                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  The path "./_lib/getTimezoneOffsetInMilliseconds/index.js" is not exported by package "date-fns":

    node_modules/date-fns/package.json:19:13:
      19 │   "exports": {
         ╵              ^

  You can mark the path "date-fns/_lib/getTimezoneOffsetInMilliseconds/index.js" as external to
  exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the
  bundle.

5 errors
/home/john/Documents/projects/project-api/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:2
`),localBundling=options.local?.tryBundle(bundleDir,options),!localBundling){const assetStagingOptions={sourcePath:this.sourcePath,bundleDir,...options};switch(options.bundlingFileAccess){case bundling_1().BundlingFileAccess.VOLUME_COPY:new(asset_staging_1()).AssetBundlingVolumeCopy(assetStagingOptions).run();break;case bundling_1().BundlingFileAccess.BIND_MOUNT:default:new(asset_staging_1()).AssetBundlingBindMount(assetStagingOptions).run();break}}}catch(err){const bundleErrorDir=bundleDir+"-error";throw fs().existsSync(bundleErrorDir)&&fs().removeSync(bundleErrorDir),fs().renameSync(bundleDir,bundleErrorDir),new Error(`Failed to bundle asset ${this.node.path}, bundle output is located at ${bundleErrorDir}: ${err}`)}if(fs_1().FileSystem.isEmpty(bundleDir)){const outputDir=localBundling?bundleDir:AssetStaging.BUNDLING_OUTPUT_DIR;throw new Error(`Bundling did not produce any output. Check that content is written to ${outputDir}.`)}}calculateHash(hashType,bundling,outputDir){if(hashType==assets_1().AssetHashType.CUSTOM||hashType==assets_1().AssetHashType.SOURCE&&bundling){const hash=crypto().createHash("sha256");return hash.update(this.customSourceFingerprint??fs_1().FileSystem.fingerprint(this.sourcePath,this.fingerprintOptions)),bundling&&hash.update(JSON.stringify(bundling)),hash.digest("hex")}switch(hashType){case assets_1().AssetHashType.SOURCE:return fs_1().FileSystem.fingerprint(this.sourcePath,this.fingerprintOptions);case assets_1().AssetHashType.BUNDLE:case assets_1().AssetHashType.OUTPUT:if(!outputDir)throw new Error(`Cannot use \`${hashType}\` hash type when \`bundling\` is not specified.`);return fs_1().FileSystem.fingerprint(outputDir,this.fingerprintOptions);default:throw new Error("Unknown asset hash type.")}}}exports.AssetStaging=AssetStaging,_a=JSII_RTTI_SYMBOL_1,AssetStaging[_a]={fqn:"aws-cdk-lib.AssetStaging",version:"2.114.0"},AssetStaging.BUNDLING_INPUT_DIR="/asset-input",AssetStaging.BUNDLING_OUTPUT_DIR="/asset-output",AssetStaging.assetCache=new(cache_1()).Cache;function renderAssetFilename(assetHash,extension=""){return`asset.${assetHash}${extension}`}function determineHashType(assetHashType,customSourceFingerprint){const hashType=customSourceFingerprint?assetHashType??assets_1().AssetHashType.CUSTOM:assetHashType??assets_1().AssetHashType.SOURCE;if(customSourceFingerprint&&hashType!==assets_1().AssetHashType.CUSTOM)throw new Error(`Cannot specify \`${assetHashType}\` for \`assetHashType\` when \`assetHash\` is specified. Use \`CUSTOM\` or leave \`undefined\`.`);if(hashType===assets_1().AssetHashType.CUSTOM&&!customSourceFingerprint)throw new Error("`assetHash` must be specified when `assetHashType` is set to `AssetHashType.CUSTOM`.");return hashType}function calculateCacheKey(props){return crypto().createHash("sha256").update(JSON.stringify(sortObject(props))).digest("hex")}function sortObject(object){if(typeof object!="object"||object instanceof Array)return object;const ret={};for(const key of Object.keys(object).sort())ret[key]=sortObject(object[key]);return ret}function findSingleFile(directory,archiveOnly){if(!fs().existsSync(directory))throw new Error(`Directory ${directory} does not exist.`);if(!fs().statSync(directory).isDirectory())throw new Error(`${directory} is not a directory.`);const content=fs().readdirSync(directory);if(content.length===1){const file=path().join(directory,content[0]),extension=getExtension(content[0]).toLowerCase();if(fs().statSync(file).isFile()&&(!archiveOnly||ARCHIVE_EXTENSIONS.includes(extension)))return file}}function determineBundledAsset(bundleDir,outputType){const archiveFile=findSingleFile(bundleDir,outputType!==bundling_1().BundlingOutput.SINGLE_FILE);switch(outputType===bundling_1().BundlingOutput.AUTO_DISCOVER&&(outputType=archiveFile?bundling_1().BundlingOutput.ARCHIVED:bundling_1().BundlingOutput.NOT_ARCHIVED),outputType){case bundling_1().BundlingOutput.NOT_ARCHIVED:return{path:bundleDir,packaging:assets_1().FileAssetPackaging.ZIP_DIRECTORY};case bundling_1().BundlingOutput.ARCHIVED:case bundling_1().BundlingOutput.SINGLE_FILE:if(!archiveFile)throw new Error("Bundling output directory is expected to include only a single file when `output` is set to `ARCHIVED` or `SINGLE_FILE`");return{path:archiveFile,packaging:assets_1().FileAssetPackaging.FILE,extension:getExtension(archiveFile)}}}function getExtension(source){for(const ext of ARCHIVE_EXTENSIONS)if(source.toLowerCase().endsWith(ext))return ext;return path().extname(source)}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ^
Error: Failed to bundle asset projectApiStack/createWorkingDay/Code/Stage, bundle output is located at /home/john/Documents/projects/project-api/cdk.out/bundling-temp-64a44bf2f0de1a13a2a49b39cab73f1feec108cd3f96e0e94a1e06f954df0738-error: Error: bash -c npx --no-install esbuild --bundle "/home/john/Documents/projects/project-api/src/lambdas/beauty-page/create-working-day.lambda.ts" --target=node20 --platform=node --outfile="/home/john/Documents/projects/project-api/cdk.out/bundling-temp-64a44bf2f0de1a13a2a49b39cab73f1feec108cd3f96e0e94a1e06f954df0738/index.js" --external:@aws-sdk/* run in directory /home/john/Documents/projects/project-api exited with status 1
    at AssetStaging.bundle (/home/john/Documents/projects/project-api/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:2:619)
    at AssetStaging.stageByBundling (/home/john/Documents/projects/project-api/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:1:5297)
    at stageThisAsset (/home/john/Documents/projects/project-api/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:1:2728)
    at Cache.obtain (/home/john/Documents/projects/project-api/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/cache.js:1:242)
    at new AssetStaging (/home/john/Documents/projects/project-api/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:1:3125)
    at new Asset (/home/john/Documents/projects/project-api/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3-assets/lib/asset.js:1:1080)
    at AssetCode.bind (/home/john/Documents/projects/project-api/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda/lib/code.js:1:4881)
    at new Function (/home/john/Documents/projects/project-api/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda/lib/function.js:1:9180)
    at new NodejsFunction (/home/john/Documents/projects/project-api/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs/lib/function.js:1:1669)
    at projectApiStack._createWoringDayLambda (/home/john/Documents/projects/project-api/lib/project-api-stack.ts:1305:20)
```

This is my AWS CDK configuration snippet

```js
// Cut

function createWoringDayLambda () {
  const handler = "createWorkingDay"

  const lambda = new aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction(this, handler, {
    entry: join(__dirname, `../src/lambdas/beauty-page/create-working-day.lambda.ts`),
    handler: handler,
    runtime: aws_lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
    architecture: aws_lambda.Architecture.ARM_64,
  });

  const options: aws_apigatewayv2.AddRoutesOptions = {
    path: "/beauty-pages/{beautyPageAlias}/specialists/{specialistId}/working-days",
    methods: [aws_apigatewayv2.HttpMethod.POST],
    integration: new HttpLambdaIntegration(`${handler}Integration`, lambda),
    authorizer: this._cognitoAuthorizer
  };

  this._apiGateway.addRoutes(options);

  this._table.grantReadWriteData(lambda);
}

// Cut
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "project-api",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "bin": {
    "project-api": "bin/project-api.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "test": "jest",
    "cdk": "cdk"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.130",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.8",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.5",
    "@types/node": "20.9.1",
    "aws-cdk": "2.114.0",
    "esbuild": "^0.19.9",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~5.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider": "^3.474.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.477.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.485.0",
    "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb": "^3.477.0",
    "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.485.0",
    "@img/sharp-linux-x64": "^0.33.1",
    "aws-cdk-lib": "2.114.0",
    "aws-lambda": "^1.0.7",
    "constructs": "^10.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^3.2.0",
    "date-fns-tz": "^2.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "sharp": "^0.33.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "cdk.out"
  ]
}
```

I import lib functions like this

```js
import { getMilliseconds } from "date-fns"
import { utcToZonedTime } from "date-fns-tz"

// cut
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

P.S. I would expect the build to run normally because I also use the `jsonwebtoken` package, which doesn't fail the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the root cause of the problem.

The `date-fns-tz@2.0.0` package does not support `date-fns@3.2.0` v3, which is causing those errors.

Track the opened GitHub issue here: https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz/issues/260

Comment: Long live to terraform,aws-cdk code is terrible, look like write a nodejs application.